# How do I use For Loop in JavaScript to show the list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, web

I am a beginner in JavaScript and I can't figure out the following problem: I am trying to create a simple JavaScript Movie List. I have 10 lists on the Movie List. I tried to show all of the lists with for loop, but it doesn't work.
Here's the code:

```
function renderModal() {
    for (let i = 0; i < listMovies.length; i++) {
        let movieData = listMovies[i];
        document.getElementById("poster").src = movieData.img;
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = movieData.name;
        document.getElementById("genre").innerHTML = movieData.genre;
        document.getElementById("rating-num").innerHTML = "Rating: "+ movieData.rating + "/10";
        document.getElementById("movie-desc").innerHTML = movieData.desc;
        document.getElementById("imdb-page").href = movieData.link;
        return movieData;
    }
}
```

What do I have to do?
Help me to fix it!.

Comment: What list are you trying to show? what output do you want exactly

Comment: You only have the necessary HTML elements for one movie it seems.

Comment: I know that it is rude to mention, but I don't see any code that add elements to HTML - not really sure how you expect multiple items to show up in a single set of elements...

Comment: Also your `return movieData;` will stop the loop dead. Not that running it more than once will change anything since you change the same elements over and over. IDs must be unique. Please post your object and HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **template** tag for list and render it into target element.I am showing an example.

Movie list

```
<div id="movieList"></div>
```

template for list

```
<template id="movieListTemplate">
    <div class="movie">
        <img src="" class="poster" alt="">
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="genre"></div>
        <div class="rating-num"></div>
        <div class="movie-desc"></div>
        <div class="imdb-page"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Javascript code:

```
if (listMovies.length > 0) {
       const movileListTemplate = document.getElementById('movieListTemplate')
       const movieRenederElement = document.getElementById('movieList')

       for(const movie of listMovies) {
           const movieEl = document.importNode(movileListTemplate.content, true)
            movieEl.querySelector('.poster').src = movie.img
            movieEl.querySelector('.title').textContent = movie.name
            //use all queryselector like above
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `return movieData;` will stop the loop dead. Not that running it more than once will change anything since you change the same elements over and over. IDs must be unique.

Here is a useful way to render an array

```js
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = listMovies.map(movieData => `<img src="${movieData.img}" />
  <h3>${movieData.name}</h3>
  <p>${movieData.genre}</p>
  <p>Rating: ${movieData.rating}/10</p>
  <p>${movieData.desc}
    <a href="${movieData.link}">IMDB</a>
  </p>`).join("<hr/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

With return movieData, the for loop will ends in advance.You should put it outside the for loop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).